# What do you call the place where you tie a horse?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, nouns, proper-nouns

Can anyone please tell me what is the exact word for this type of arrangement to tie a horse? Or is it just called a stable?

[image: Horse tied to a brach]

[Image source: https://www.reddit.com/r/reddeadredemption/comments/a1hcyo/am_i_the_only_one_annoyed_that_the_arabian_horse/]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hitchrack) calls this a

> **hitchrack**
> a fixed horizontal rail to which a horse or team can be fastened to prevent straying

Sometimes also called a

> **hitching rail**

Please see [Every equestrian needs to know how to tie a horse safely](https://horserookie.com/how-tie-horse-hitching-post/)

Comment: Also called a hitching post.

Comment: I would probably say, “hitch (or tie) to a post.” But I don’t have a lot of experience with horses.

Comment: A stable is a building where horses sleep. It is not a small thing you tie a horse to.

Comment: @eps, wouldn't a "hitching post" lack the rail? And be just a 'post'?

Comment: The linked article also shows a "hitching ring". So it looks like in general a "thing" intended to have a horse tied to it is a "hitching thing".